# NetPortGradient returns "floating-point overflow" for this simple network

Tags: warning-messages, neural-networks

Consider this simple network that computes the following function:
$$ \left\{ \begin{matrix} xy & \mbox{if} \;x,y>0 \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{matrix} \right.$$

The net looks like:

```
net = NetChain[{ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], AggregationLayer[Times, 1]}]
```

This works correctly as:

```
In[2]:= net[{4, 2}]

Out[2]= 8.    

In[3]:= net[{4, -2}]    

Out[3]= 0.    

In[4]:= net[{-4, -2}]    

Out[4]= 0.
```

However if try to evaluate the gradient in a given point, this returns a floating point error when either $x$ or $y$ are smaller than $0$.

```
In[5]:= net[{4, -2}, NetPortGradient["Input"]]

During evaluation of In[5]:= NetGraph::netnan: A floating-point overflow, underflow, or division by zero occurred while evaluating the net.

Out[5]= $Failed
```

Why this happens? Is there a way to avoid this?

PS: this is a very simplified example of the minimal network required to reproduce the error, extracted from a much more complicated loss function

EDIT:
After posting the question, I discovered that the error can be reproduced also replacing `Ramp` with `# - # &`, but does not occur with `# - # + 1 &`

Link to question on Wolfram Community  [[link]](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1644804?p_p_auth=UCON8lyQ) [link updated 02/04/2019]

Comment: Please edit both this and your Wolfram Community post and cross-link them.

Comment: Which is the best way to do it? You insert the link? Is it considered "unpolite" to post the question in both places?

Comment: Isn't this to do with the fact that `Ramp` will return `0` for negative numbers? Does `NetPortGradient` do some division somewhere?

Comment: I suspect that too. If you look at the edit that’s exactly what I tested. Despite this, the function f(x,y)=0 has a very well defined gradient: (0,0) everywhere! Moreover also f(x,y)=1 has the same null gradient, but the problem doesn’t occur with it…

Comment: If you replace the `Times` with `Total` it does not cause the error...

Comment: No, it is not impolite to cross-post. Just put a link at the top (or bottom) of both posts and link to its counterpart on the other site. This is so that people won't spend time to solve an already solved problem.

Comment: The way you did it is fine.

Comment: And still, in the function above, if you replace $xy$ with $x+y$, the function is equal to zero for all $x or y < 0$

Comment: Yes - I suspect `NetPortGradient` is seeing the `Times` and reversing it (eg, dividing) in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error seems to occur when NetPortGradient tries to evaluate the gradient of a product in a point where **both product's terms are null with null derivative**. This is exactly what happens, for example, with the function $f(x,y) = x\cdot y$ in a region where both $x$ and $y$ are constantly $0$.

This is, at least in my opinion, a bug of NetPortGradient.

This cause also NetTrain to fail, as it fails to perform gradient descend.

To overcome the issue I rewrote the problem as $$ \left\{ \begin{matrix} (x+1)(y+1) - (x +y) -1 & \mbox{if} \;x,y>0 \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{matrix} \right.$$

Mathematically, this is equal to the function above, as the function is just a convoluted way of writing $x\cdot y$. However, the product is perform between $(x+1)$ and $(y+1)$ that are non-zero everywhere (except for a point).

This allow the gradient to be correctly evaluated.

In the wolfram's Network language, this can be implemented as

```
net = NetGraph[
  {
   "ramp" -> ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
   "x+1" -> ElementwiseLayer[# + 1 &],
   "times" -> AggregationLayer[Times, 1],
   "sum" -> AggregationLayer[Total, 1],
   "x-y-1" -> ThreadingLayer[#1 - #2 - 1 &]
   },
  {
   "ramp" -> "x+1",
   "x+1" -> "times",
   "ramp" -> "sum",
   {"times", "sum"} -> "x-y-1"
   }
  ]
```

and indeed

```
In[116]:= net[{4, 2}]

Out[116]= 8.

In[117]:= net[{-4, -2}]

Out[117]= 0.

In[118]:= net[{4, -2}, NetPortGradient["Input"]]

Out[118]= {0., 0.}

In[119]:= net[{-4, -2}, NetPortGradient["Input"]]

Out[119]= {0., 0.}
```

It works!